# SQL - Query only the first 25 columns in that table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

75 columns in a table - I want to query only the first 25 columns in that table without naming each column name.... can you assist with a SQL query....

I been playing with the following:

```
Select Table_Name, Count(*) As ColumnCount
From   Information_Schema.Columns
Group By Table_Name
Order By Table_Name
```

Doesn't meet my output........

If a Table has 75 columns, How can I see the first 25 columns without naming each column name? Don't want to delete Columns Only want to see the first 25 columns out of 75 columns in the same table.....TOP is not enable need another work around....

Comment: Just bite the bullet and name the columns. You'll be better off rather than trying to cobble together a dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: absolutely, seconded!

Answer (score 4):

First 25 columns in a table query built into @query and then executed. Substitute correct @target_table value.

```
DECLARE
    @target_table sysname
,   @query nvarchar(max)

SET
    @target_table = '_dimAreaOverlay'

; with of_interest as
(
SELECT
    SS.name AS schemaname
,   T.name AS tablename
,   SC.name AS columname
FROM
    sys.schemas SS
    inner join
        sys.tables T
        ON T.schema_id = SS.schema_id
    inner join
        sys.columns SC
        ON SC.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE
    T.name = @target_table
    AND SC.column_id < 26
)
, c AS
(
    SELECT 
        STUFF((
        SELECT 
            ',' + QUOTENAME(I.columname)
        FROM
            of_interest I
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '') AS column_list
    ,   OI.tablename
    ,   OI.schemaname
    FROM
        of_interest OI
    GROUP BY
        OI.schemaname
    ,    OI.tablename
)
SELECT
    @query = 'SELECT ' 
    + C.column_list 
    + ' FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(C.schemaname) 
    + '.' 
    + QUOTENAME(C.tablename)
FROM C

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: +1 For `sysname` but you should use `QUOTENAME` rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself so it works correctly for object names containing `]`

Comment: Amending now, I wasn't familiar with [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) until you mentioned it

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the table in Management Studio Object Explorer.
2. Right click it and choose `Script Table As -> Select To -> New Query Editor Window`
3. Delete unwanted columns.

Comment: Actually that is the way to do it.. assuming you have management studio , been a while since I did that I forgot it had that functionality

Comment: Seems by far the easiest way to do it to me. It would be possible to come up with an SQL query to do the string concatenation but this shouldn't come up so frequently as to make the effort worthwhile.

Comment: Generate Scripts if you want to recreate indexes and constraints!